# My attempt at GNU echo in rust

Tags: rust, memory-management

This is my first post. I'm trying to learn Rust and I recently finished reading the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/).

For further learning I decided to try to reimplement some GNU core utilities in Rust.

This is [my approach to echo](https://github.com/roocker/rr_echo/blob/master/src/main.rs).

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, env};
struct Config {
    backslash_escapes: RefCell<bool>,
    trailing_newline: RefCell<bool>,
}

impl Config {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Config {
            backslash_escapes: RefCell::new(false),
            trailing_newline: RefCell::new(true),
        }
    }

    fn find_flags<'a>(
        &'a self,
        input: impl Iterator<Item = String> + 'a,
    ) -> impl Iterator<Item = String> + 'a {
        let input = input.filter_map(|word| match word.as_str() {
            "-e" => {
                *self.backslash_escapes.borrow_mut() = true;
                None
            }
            "-n" => {
                *self.trailing_newline.borrow_mut() = false;
                None
            }
            "-en" => {
                *self.backslash_escapes.borrow_mut() = true;
                *self.trailing_newline.borrow_mut() = false;
                None
            }
            "-ne" => {
                *self.backslash_escapes.borrow_mut() = true;
                *self.trailing_newline.borrow_mut() = false;
                None
            }
            "-E" => {
                *self.backslash_escapes.borrow_mut() = false;
                None
            }
            _ => Some(word),
        });
        input
    }
}

fn main() {
    // println!("{}", std::env::args().skip(1).format(" ")); // most simple version?

    let config = Config::new();
    let input = env::args().skip(1);

    // does defining content here increase overhead?
    let mut content = config.find_flags(input);

    // i dont like that i have to use replace_escapes for first_word seperatly here.
    // i can try to map over the whole content first and replace escapes words (w/o consuming the Iterator!)?
    if let Some(first_word) = &content.next() {
        if *config.backslash_escapes.borrow() {
            print!("{}", replace_escapes(first_word));
        } else {
            print!("{}", first_word);
        }
        content.for_each(|word| {
            if let Some(word) = Some(word) {
                if *config.backslash_escapes.borrow() {
                    print!(" {}", replace_escapes(&word));
                } else {
                    print!(" {}", word);
                }
            }
        });
        if *config.trailing_newline.borrow() {
            println!("");
        }
    };

    fn replace_escapes(word: &String) -> &str {
        match word.as_str() {
            "\\a" => "\x07",       // alert (BEL)
            "\\b" => "\x08",       // backspace
            "\\c" => "(STOPPPP!)", // produce no further output
            "\\e" => "\x1b",       // escape
            "\\f" => "\x0c",       // form feed
            "\\n" => "\n",         // newline
            "\\r" => "\r",         // carriage return
            "\\t" => "\t",         // horizontal tab
            "\\v" => "\x0B",       // vertical tab
            _ => word,
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to incorporate feedback of other reimplementation's of echo. So for my version I tried:

- not use crates
- to not allocate the data to a vector, and to not consume the Iterator until the output.
- still implement option flag, although this gave me substantial headache with borrowing rules.

My questions:

- I'm sure the Overhead of using a vector is minimal in this case, still I wanted to learn about the functional programming approaches rust has to offer with Iterator
- At any Point in my code? Do I allocate data that is not needed? for example by defining the content variable?
- Is there a more elegant solution to using the boolean variable `backslash_escapes`, which I capture in the closure of the `find_flags` method?
- if I read the book correctly `RefCell` has an overhead in enforcing the ownership rules at runtime. Is this CPU overhead? Is it still worth not collecting the Iterator in a Vector?
- Am I overcomplicating things? Or is an approach like this useful when working with larger amounts of data?

I appreciate every roast, criticism, and comment!

Comment: I like your first sentence. Congratulations for that. And welcome.

Answer (score 7):

Well, first of all, your code doesn't work the way it should. :D
Here is the output of `echo` for an example input

```bash
$echo -e 'ff\ngg\n' 'aaa\tbbb'

ff
gg
 aaa    bbb
```

And here is the output of your program

```bash
./main -e 'ff\ngg\n' 'aaa\tbbb'

ff\ngg\n aaa\tbbb
```

As you can see, it does not print whitespace properly. Writing unit tests for your code can prevent such mistakes.

The iterator approach seems interesting. But I don't think there is any need to use RefCell here. It contradicts the whole point of functional programming which is having immutable states.

Since flags only appear before other arguments I think you can check for flags first, create your config by consuming them, and then return the rest of the iterator for further processing.

Something like this:

```rust
struct Config {
    backslash_escapes: bool,
    trailing_newline: bool,
}

impl Config {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Config {
            backslash_escapes: false,
            trailing_newline: true,
        }
    }
    
    fn make_new_config(self, flag: &str) -> Config {
        match flag {
            "-e" => Config {
                backslash_escapes: true,
                ..self
            },

            "-n" => Config {
                trailing_newline: false,
                ..self
            },

            "-en" | "-ne" => Config {
                backslash_escapes: true,
                trailing_newline: false,
            },

            "-E" => Config {
                backslash_escapes: false,
                ..self
            },
            _ => self,
        }
    }

    fn check_flags(
        input: impl Iterator<Item = String>,
        mut config: Config,
    ) -> (Config, impl Iterator<Item = String>) {
        let mut peekable = input.peekable();

        while let Some(flag) = peekable.next_if(|arg| match arg.as_str() {
            "-E" | "-e" | "-n" | "-en" | "-ne" => true,
            _ => false,
        }) {
            config = config.make_new_config(&flag);
        }

        (config, peekable)
    }
}
```

Comment: echo for me `echo 'ff\ngg\n' 'aaa\tbbb'` prints this: `ff\ngg\n aaa\tbbb` so no extra white space of next  line or tab, do you mean maybe printf? Maybe you wanted to say the `-e` option? `echo -e 'ff\ngg\n' 'aaa\tbbb'
ff
gg
 aaa bbb`

Comment: yes, i meant it with `-e`  option. i tested it on bash which has builtin echo command with `-e` as the default case. but for GNU echo program -E is the default case.
this post explains the difference:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153660/why-echo-help-doesnt-give-me-help-page-of-echo

Comment: And you could `#[derive(clap::Parser)]` for the config above, if OP would not like to avoid using other crates.